# Copy or move file into directory with parallel processing from another process

Tags: unix, process, filesystems, aix

I'm running two processes on AIX. Process one is generating several files, process two does backups from all files that are in a backup directory.

Process one will copy or move the files into the backup directory. Since process two is always running in the background there is the risk of it starting a backup of a file that is still in the process of being copied or moved and therefore incomplete. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Process one should create files in another directory (on the same disk); and when a file is created, move it into the final directory. Move is an atomic operation, so process2 will only find complete files.

Edit: on AIX, /usr/bin/istat helps to make sure that two directories (or files) are on the same disk/partition/device, e.g.

```
for Dir in /home /home/zsiga /tmp;
    do /usr/bin/istat "$Dir" | grep device;
done
```

Result:

```
Inode  2 on device 10/8 Directory
Inode 33 on device 10/8 Directory
Inode  2 on device 10/7 Directory
```

The first two are on the same disk/partition/device (10/8); the last one is on another device (10/7)

Comment: How can you make sure that you are on the same disk?

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: Instead of moving could I also create a hardlink? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894407/is-the-lncreate-hardlink-command-atomic-on-aix

Comment: Sure, as moving a file is basically creating a new hardlink, then removing the old one.