# Is the ln(create hardlink) command atomic on AIX?

Tags: linux, file, unix, filesystems, aix

Is the [`ln`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/l_commands/ln.html)(create hardlink) command atomic on AIX?

The problem is that there are two processes running and the process that creates the hardlink is not the same process that reads it. I want to ensure that the second process will not run into trouble with partially created hardlinks if there is such a thing. See also: [Copy or move file into directory with parallel processing from another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856442/copy-or-move-file-into-directory-with-parallel-processing-from-another-process)

Comment: It's not _command_ it's a _sytem call_. Yes it's atomic.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond according to wikipedia it's a command https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to add a note, but it was too late: the main function of `ln(1)` program (or shell-builtin) is calling `link(2)` system-call; the latter is an atomic operation.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond can you provide a link to where it says that it is atomic? Thanks

Comment: AIX is supposed to be POSIX-compliant, so you can rely on POSIX description of `link(2)` and `rename(2)` https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html